# Process multiple forms with a single ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I finally got my original problem fixed, so decided to create another issue. I now have 2 forms I am trying to get to process through ajax. The first form will run fine and stay on the current page. The second form, however, is taking me to admin-ajax.php. The form content is saved fine, just not staying on the current page like the first form. My code is below.

**Forms**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="commentform">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="commentbox" rows="5" cols="120" required></textarea><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="eventid" id="eventid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commentform">
    <button class="commentbtn">Add Comment</button>
</form>

<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="commentform">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="commentbox" rows="5" cols="120" required></textarea><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="eventid" id="eventid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="commentid" value="<?php echo $commid; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commentform">
    <button class="commentbtn">Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#commentform').submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var commentform = $('#commentform');
        $.ajax({
            url: commentform.attr('action'),
            data: commentform.serialize(), // form data
            type: commentform.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                commentform.find('button').text('Processing...');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                commentform.find('button').text('Add Comment');
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP Function**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_commentform', 'comment_submit');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_commentform', 'comment_submit');
function comment_submit() {
    global $wpdb;

    $eventid = $_POST["eventid"];
    $userid = $_POST["userid"];
    $comment = $_POST["comment"];
    $commid = $_POST["commentid"];

    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $inserttable = $wpdb->prefix . "event_comments";
    if ($commid == "") {
        $data = array(
            'eventid' => $eventid,
            'userid' => $userid,
            'content' => $comment,
            'datesaved' => $date,
        );
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'eventid' => $eventid,
            'userid' => $userid,
            'content' => $comment,
            'datesaved' => $date,
            'parentid' => $commid,
        );        
    }
    $wpdb->insert($inserttable, $data);

    $commentctr = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "cmc_communitybb_event_comments where eventid=$eventid");

    echo "<h2>Comments</h2>";
    echo "<h3>$commentctr Total Comments</h3>";
    die;
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique.`$("#commentform")` only selects the first one. Use a class instead of ID.